# sql query to get only friday dates between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle

Question: How do i select only friday dates between two dates in oracle

```
 SELECT dates,TO_CHAR(dates,'day-mon-yyyy')
 FROM
 (SELECT to_date('01-jan-12','dd-mon-yy')+rownum -1 AS dates
  FROM addresses
 WHERE rownum <= to_date('31-jan-12','dd-mon-yy')- to_date('01-jan-12','dd-mon-yy')+1)
WHERE upper(regexp_substr(TO_CHAR(dates,'day-mon-yy'),'([[:alpha:]])+'))=upper('FRIDAY');
```

i need Output like:

```
06-JAN-12 FRIDAY                              
13-JAN-12 FRIDAY                              
20-JAN-12 FRIDAY                              
27-JAN-12 FRIDAY                              
03-FEB-12 FRIDAY                              
10-FEB-12 FRIDAY                              
17-FEB-12 FRIDAY                              
24-FEB-12 FRIDAY                              
02-MAR-12 FRIDAY                              
09-MAR-12 FRIDAY                              
16-MAR-12 FRIDAY                              
23-MAR-12 FRIDAY                              
30-MAR-12 FRIDAY
```

visit more sql queries: [SQL Query Interview Questions](http://www.plsqlinformation.com/2014/01/sql-query-interview-questions.html)

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: What is your question/problem/error? What you've shown needs single quotes around the date strings, for start, but... seems rather complicated anyway, what is the relevant of the addresses table?

Comment: Thanq u very much,i forgot single quotes now it is working fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will get an error from what you posted because the values you've used as the first argument to `to_char()` aren't enclosed in single quotes:

```
select to_date(01-jan-12,'dd-mon-yy') from dual;

ORA-00904: "JAN": invalid identifier
```

Because there are no quotes, `jan` is interpreted as an identifier, and there is (presumably) no column call `JAN` in your addresses table. It's also bad practice to use 2-digit years, and where you must (from really old data) it's usually better to use `RR` than `YY`. The month names are also affected by your NLS settings, so it's safer to use month numbers than names; if you really want names the `to_char()` function has a third argument to control the language.

You are doing this in quite a complicated way, and you're relying on the addresses table having enough rows. Specifying that you want the day name in lower case via `day` instead of `DAY`, then making it uppercase, then stripping off the bits of the string - that you specified in the first place! - to only get the day name, and then comparing that on the assumption (again) that the NLS settings will give you English day names anyway is... unnecessarily convoluted. As is calling `upper()` against a fixed string literal you you can (and are) supply in uppercase already.

Instead of

```
WHERE upper(regexp_substr(TO_CHAR(dates,'day-mon-yy'),'([[:alpha:]])+'))=upper('FRIDAY');
```

you could do any of these, or other variations:

```
WHERE regexp_substr(TO_CHAR(dates,'DAY-mon-
y'),'([[:alpha:]])+')=upper('FRIDAY');
WHERE TO_CHAR(dates,'DAY')='FRIDAY   ';
WHERE TRIM(TO_CHAR(dates,'DAY'))=upper('FRIDAY');
WHERE TO_CHAR(dates,'FMDAY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')='FRIDAY';
```

You could avoid relying on the addresses table by using a hierarchical query, against the `dual` table:

```
SELECT next_day(date '2012-01-01' - 1, 'FRIDAY') + (7 * (level - 1))
FROM dual
CONNECT BY next_day(date '2012-01-01' - 1, 'FRIDAY') + (7 * (level - 1))
  <= date '2012-03-31';
```

Using `next_day` also relies on NLS settings though, so unless you can always control the session date language, it might be safer (if a little less efficient) to get all the dates and then filter them in an NLS-independent way:

```
SELECT dates, to_char(dates, 'FMDAY')
FROM (
  SELECT date '2012-01-01' + level - 1 AS dates
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY level <= date '2012-03-31' - date '2012-01-01'
)
WHERE to_char(dates, 'FMDAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'FRIDAY';

DATES     TO_CHAR(DATES,'FMDAY')              
--------- ------------------------------------
06-JAN-12 FRIDAY                              
13-JAN-12 FRIDAY                              
20-JAN-12 FRIDAY                              
27-JAN-12 FRIDAY                              
03-FEB-12 FRIDAY                              
10-FEB-12 FRIDAY                              
17-FEB-12 FRIDAY                              
24-FEB-12 FRIDAY                              
02-MAR-12 FRIDAY                              
09-MAR-12 FRIDAY                              
16-MAR-12 FRIDAY                              
23-MAR-12 FRIDAY                              
30-MAR-12 FRIDAY                              

13 rows selected.
```

As @mathguy pointed out in a comment, although `next_day()` is NLS-sensitive, you can use an expression for the second argument, so instead of hard-coding the day name you can do this:

```
next_day(date '2012-01-01' - 1, to_char(date '1999-12-31', 'FMDAY'))
```

where 1999-12-31 can be any date known to be a Friday; and if you don't mind the expression in the select list and connect-by clause being different (and really, you - and I - shouldn't!) you can reduce the computational cost of that check with:

```
SELECT dates, to_char(dates, 'FMDAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
FROM (
  SELECT next_day(date '2012-01-01' - 1,
    to_char(date '1999-12-31', 'FMDAY')) + (7 * (level - 1)) AS dates
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY level <= 1 + (date '2012-03-31' - next_day(date '2012-01-01' - 1,
    to_char(date '1999-12-31', 'FMDAY')))/7
);
```

which gets the same 13 rows as above, regardless of the session's date language. If you want the output to be in the session language too, just remove the overriding third argument to `to_char()`.

Comment: The solution using `next_day()` is probably the most efficient. To make it independent of the invoking session's language, we can compute `to_char(some_date, 'Day')` for a `some_date` known to be a Friday - then use that in the call to `next_day()`. The same solution can be made more efficient by solving the inequality for `level` in `connect by` (that is, write it as `level <= 1 + (<max_date> - <first_friday>) / 7`. This way the RHS is computed just once for the whole query; in the current form, there are additional arithmetic calculation for each row.

Comment: @mathguy - huh, for some reason I thought the second argument to `next_day()` had to be a literal not an expression; no idea where I got that from as it clearly isn't true. Also agree about moving the calculation to RHS for efficiency; for readability using the same expression in the connect-by as the select list can be helpful, but yes the cost difference here could be significant so that's not a convincing argument in this case. Thanks.